# Efficient substitute for std::map::insert_or_assign with hint

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

I'm trying to write a substitute for [`std::map::insert_or_assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) that takes the `hint` parameter, for build environments that don't support C++17.

I'd like for this substitute to be just as efficient, and not require that the mapped type be *DefaultConstructible*. The latter requirement rules out `map[key] = value`.

I've come up with this:

```cpp
template <class M, class K, class T>
typename M::iterator insert_or_assign(M& map, typename M::const_iterator hint,
                                      K&& key, T&& value)
{
    using std::forward;
    auto old_size = map.size();
    auto iter = map.emplace_hint(hint, forward<K>(key), forward<T>(value));

    // If the map didn't grow, the key already already existed and we can directly
    // assign its associated value.
    if (map.size() == old_size)
        iter->second = std::forward<T>(value);
    return iter;
}
```

However, I don't know if I can trust `std::map` not to move-assign the value twice in the case where the key already existed. Is this safe? If not, is there a safe way to efficiently implement a substitute for `std::map::insert_or_assign` taking a `hint` parameter?

Comment: Not normative, but cppreference: *The element may be constructed even if there already is an element with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed element will be destroyed immediately.* https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace

Comment: not the same text in `emplace_hint`, but I believe bot functions have this same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks! I guess that rules out my proposed substitute. I didn't think to read the docs for `emplace` to see if the value could be moved "by accident".

Comment: If I recall, don't most map implementations just ignore the hint entirely?

Comment: @MooingDuck, I hope not, as entries are likely to already be sorted as they are inserted for my use case. I could check the hint manually, but it would duplicate what's already done by implementations that don't ignore the hint.

Comment: For my probably-pre-sorted use case, I think I'm better off checking manually just before `end()` instead of relying on `std::map`'s hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per NathanOliver's comment, where he cited the cppreference [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) for `std::map::emplace`:

> The element may be constructed even if there already is an element
> with the key in the container, in which case the newly constructed
> element will be destroyed immediately.

If we assume the same applies for `std::map::emplace_hint`, then the value could moved away prematurely in the solution I proposed in my question.

I've come up with this other solution (**NOT TESTED**), which only `forward`s the value once. I admit it's not pretty. :-)

```cpp
// Take 'hint' as a mutating iterator to avoid an O(N) conversion.
template <class M, class K, class T>
typename M::iterator insert_or_assign(M& map, typename M::iterator hint,
                                      K&& key, T&& value)
{
    using std::forward;

#ifdef __cpp_lib_map_try_emplace
    return map.insert_or_assign(hint, forward<K>(key), forward<T>(value);
#else
    // Check if the given key goes between `hint` and the entry just before
    // hint. If not, check if the given key matches the entry just before hint.
    if (hint != map.begin())
    {
        auto previous = hint;
        --previous; // O(1)
        auto comp = map.key_comp();
        if (comp(previous->first, key)) // key follows previous
        {
            if (comp(key, hint->first)) // key precedes hint
            {
                // Should be O(1)
                return map.emplace_hint(hint, forward<K>(key),
                                        forward<T>(value));
            }

        }
        else if (!comp(key, previous->first)) // key equals previous
        {
            previous->second = forward<T>(value); // O(1)
            return previous;
        }
    }

    // If this is reached, then the hint has failed.
    // Check if key already exists. If so, assign its associated value.
    // If not, emplace the new key-value pair.
    auto iter = map.find(key); // O(log(N))
    if (iter != map.end())
        iter->second = forward<T>(value);
    else
        iter = map.emplace(forward<K>(key), forward<T>(value)); // O(log(N))
    return iter;
#endif
}
```

I hope somebody else will come up with a nicer solution!

Note that I check for the `__cpp_lib_map_try_emplace` [feature test macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) to test if `std::map::insert_or_assign` is supported before resorting to this ugly mess.

---

**EDIT**: Removed the the slow iterator arithmetic silliness in attempting to check if the key already exists at `hint`.

---

**EDIT 2**: `hint` is now taken as a mutating iterator to avoid an expensive O(N) conversion if it was otherwise passed as a `const_iterator`. This allows me to manually check the hint and perform an O(1) insertion or assignment if the hint succeeds.

Comment: @MooingDuck D'oh! You're right of course. I forgot that `std::map` is node-based. Silly me.

Comment: Removed the slow iterator arithmetic silliness.

Comment: The edited solution is still O(logN) in the case where the key doesn't exist and the hint succeeds. :-(

Comment: You could check if `hint` _is_ the node, and skip the `find` in that case. Just don't increment/decrement it.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I would still need to convert the hint into a mutating iterator, which you pointed out is O(N). What I could do instead is take the `hint` parameter as a regular iterator instead of a const_iterator.

Comment: I've got a version now that should be O(1) if the hint succeeds for either insertion or assignment. However, if the hint fails, the map is searched twice for insertion.